# jQuery Toggle Animation for Bottom Tabs

Tags: jquery, animation, tabs, slide

I'm trying to build a set of tabs that rise and fall from the bottom.
Here is my jquery code so far

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $(".tab").click(function() { 
        if($(event.target).parent().css('top') == '230px')
            {$(event.target).parent().stop().animate({top:'0px'},1000);};
        if($(event.target).parent().css('top') == '0px')
            {$(event.target).parent().stop().animate({top:'230px'},1000);};
    });
});
```

Here is my first crack:
http://jsfiddle.net/X3cbG/4/

My issue is the following:
Because of my html, buttons 1, 2 and 3 are "covered" by the fourth div.

Anyone know how to work around this? either in HTML or jquery?

Comment: you seem to be horribly misusing `toggle()` API. How about reading docs to figure what you should be passing there?

Comment: Yep! I sure was. I have made the jquery work to my liking, now. So the only issue is the covering of the first three divs. Any ideas on that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your tab CSS class to:

```
.tab {position:relative; z-index:999; width:100px; text-align:center; cursor:pointer; background:rgb(54, 25, 25); background: rgba(54, 25, 25, .5);}
```

Used relative position with 999 z-index which seems to solve the issue you mentioned.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/X3cbG/5/)

Comment: That's it! Thanks for the help. Simple solution.

Answer (score 0):

For the jquery:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $(".tab").click(function() {
    var getId = $(this).attr('id');
    var top = $('#Sbox'+getId).css('top');
    $('.Sbox').animate({top:'230'}, 1000);
    move(getId, top);
  });
});

 function move(getId, top) {
            if(top == '0px' || top == 'auto')
            {
                $('#Sbox'+getId).animate({top:'230'}, 1000);
            }
            else if(top == '230px')
            {
                $('#Sbox'+getId).animate({top:'0'}, 1000);
            }
        }
```

Comment: I'm looking at both my final jquery and your suggestion here...What if I wanted the preceding tab to go back down when another tab is clicked...any ideas?

Comment: hey - i edited the response: just add before the move fn $('.Sbox').animate({top:'230'}, 1000); and everything is ok :D